# how to get exe files using fs.readdirsync() in electron js

Tags: node.js, electron, fs

I want to get the list of exe or desktop application(installed local PC) in electron js desktop application.I tried require('fs') but it list only folder from root path.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const root = fs.readdirSync('/')
console.log(root);
```

how to get only exe file

Comment: installed apps in the system or just exe files present in a directory?

Comment: installed apps .EX gaming application

Answer (score 1):

A simple way on Windows. Might take some time to retrieve the list.

```
const { execSync } = require('child_process');

let list = execSync('wmic product get name,version');
console.log(list.toString());
```

The best way would be writing a native node module using N-API to do this.

Comment: execSync('wmic product get name,version'); ? what we are giving here..I want to list all the exe files in windows .In your code list shows nothing

Comment: can we launch some apps from this list .. using execFile() like dynamically